# Calling parent class within class method gives me "matching method signature" warning

Tags: objective-c, warnings, parent, signature

I have a class that has two classes A and B added to it. In a method in class A, I am trying to call a class B method

Let's assume that the parent class is debugZoneScene, debugZoneLayer is class A and tetraCounter is class B.

Here is a method from debugZoneLayer (class A):

```
-(void) getHeroVel {
    DebugZoneScene *debugZoneScene = (DebugZoneScene*)self.parent;

    [debugZoneScene.tetraCounter setTetras]; 
}
```

It calls the method, but I get the warning:

***'-[DebugZoneLayer getHeroVel]':
'CCNode' may not respond to '-setTetras' (Messages without a matching method signature will be assumed to return 'id' and accept '...' as arguments.)***

I've tried Googling this, but I couldn't really find anything that related exactly to my problem. I am using Cocos2D, but I think this problem doesn't have anything to do directly with that, and can still be resolved having knowledge in Objective C. Any ideas?

Comment: Methods should not be prefixed with `get` outside of very special circumstances.  Similarly, methods should not generally be prefixed with `set` unless they are part of a setter/getter pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it thinks that `debugZoneScene.tetraCounter` is an object of type `CCNode`, not whatever your `ClassB` is. Check how `tetraCounter` is declared and allocated in `DebugZoneScene`.

You can make the warning go away by casting:

```
[(ClassB *)(debugZoneScene.tetraCounter) setTetras];
```

this tells the compiler that you don't care what it thinks and you're sure that the object is `ClassB`. This doesn't solve the actual problem, however.

Comment: Thanks Josh, my pointer in interface and the property was different! That's what caused it.  I'll look into this more to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo really fits you... without more details about the signature of setTetras, it will be quite difficult to guess what is wrong in your code ^^

Anyway did you #import the header for TatraCounter class declaration, so that the file where you wrote this code knows about the methods available (and their signature) for the TetraCounter objects?

Comment: Yes, thanks I did. Wrote @class TetraCounter; under the import, the pointer in interface TetraCounter *tetraCounter;, the property @property(nonatomic, retain) TetraCounter *tetraCounter;, and synthesized @synthesize tetraCounter;.

Comment: So you only did a forward declaration of the class with @class ? (Anyway please update you question to give such details). This does not gives enough info for the compiler to guess the methods this class exposes. You need to #import the class, not only forward-declare it